# Issue running GDAL_Translate on Redhat PPC64

Tags: python, geotiff-tiff, gdal-translate, hdf, red-hat

I try to run the gdal_translate command to extract and convert the MODIS hdf file into its respective band raster tif on a Redhat PPC64 environment and I encountered following error:

[image]

with my command:

```
gdal_translate -sds MOD09A1.A2018273.h27v07.006.2018290185611.hdf MOD09A1.A2018273.h27v07.006.2018290185611.tif
```

I try to run this command in other environments, it is  working fine. Therefore, I would like to know is there a workaround using python methods that I can look into to extract band raster from MODIS hdf file?

Comment: Do you have same GDAL versions? Check with "gdalinfo --version"

Comment: @user30184 under Ubuntu is 2.1.3, under Windows 2.2.4, under Redhat is 2.3.0.

Comment: There has been some changes in hdf driver in GDAL 2.3.0 https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/Release/2.3.0-News. Could you share that MODIS file for testing?

Comment: @user30184 how to share file?

Comment: A link to file if you have downloaded the file from some open service, otherwise through some file sharing service like Dropbox or WeTransfer.

Comment: @user30184 here's the link: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AtzptwDxKpw0iVfVViYfspd6568n

Comment: I tried your command with GDAL 2.4.0dev version and it had no problem at all. The error seems to be somehow related to your Redhat environment.

Comment: @user30184: thanks for your help. I have tested on the other RedHat environment, the error message replicate. It seems that GDAL framework cannot function well on RedHat. I will close case for this. Thanks.